# Get first occurrence of XSLT stylesheet

Tags: xslt

I have the following code which I use to get the sum of product values.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//fn:array[@key= 'Items']/fn:map[*[@key = 'OrderId'][.= $OrderId ] and *[@key = 'Type'][.= 'ServiceRevenue' ] ] ">
                        <amount>
                           <xsl:value-of select="fn:map[@key ='Amount']/*[@key = 'Net']" />
                        </amount>
                     </xsl:for-each>
```

I am trying to only calculate the first occurrence where `[*[@key = 'OrderId'][.= $OrderId ]`.

I tried the following, but I am still getting all the occurrences:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//fn:array[@key= 'Items']/fn:map[*[@key = 'OrderId'][.= $OrderId ][0] and *[@key = 'Type'][.= 'ServiceRevenue' ] ] ">
                        <amount>
                           <xsl:value-of select="fn:map[@key ='Amount']/*[@key = 'Net']" />
                        </amount>
                     </xsl:for-each>
```

Sample JSON:

```
[
   {
      "Items":[
         {
            "Id":"5b44f410-7034-4972-919d-acac00ead7e9",
            "OrderId":"e7791603-ca5f-47c4-9b0c-acac00ead753",
            "Type":"ServiceRevenue",
            "Amount":{
               "Value":25.0,
               "Net":25.0,
               "Tax":0.0
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {

      "Items":[
         {
            "Id":"5b44f410-7034-4972-919d-acac00ead7e9",
            "OrderId":"e7791603-ca5f-47c4-9b0c-acac00ead753",
            "Type":"ServiceRevenue",
            "Amount":{
               "Value":25.0,
               "Net":25.0,
               "Tax":0.0
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I only want to calculate the Amount of the first Item occurrence where the `OrderId = 'e7791603-ca5f-47c4-9b0c-acac00ead753'`

Comment: A positional predicate in XPath to select the first item is `[1]` not `[0]` but it is not clear whether you want it applied on the `fn:map` element or the `*` inside, it might help to show a minimal but representative XML sample.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I have two Items arrays in my JSON, and I am looping through both Item arrays, but I want to only pull data from the first array Item where I have the match [*[@key = 'OrderId'][.= $OrderId ]

Comment: As I said, show us small but representative samples of input and wanted output, then I am sure we can help correct the path and/or predicates. Your latest comment doesn't clarify (to me, at least) where exactly you want to restrict processing to one particular element with a positional predicate.

Comment: Does `fn:array[@key= 'Items'][fn:map[*[@key = 'OrderId'][.= $OrderId ] and *[@key = 'Type'][.= 'ServiceRevenue' ] ]][1]/fn:map` help? Not quite sure why you use a `for-each` if you want to process a single item.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thank you, it doesn't seem to be working the code, but I get the idea and will be tweaking it, thanks a lot